# Is 0E0 a valid JSON number

Tags: json

A very short question.

I'm writing a little minimal parser, and looking at the following diagram for the JSON description:

[image: Description of number from http://json.org/index.html]

(http://json.org/index.html) The diagram seems to suggest to me that 0E0  is just valid anomoly for '0'?  Or is it invalid?

Comment: Yes, it is a valid alternative for 0, just like +0, and 0E10. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: It just looks wrong.  I would be curious to hear how well known parsers cope with this... Haven't had time to check yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a valid number - `0` * (`10` ^ `0`). This evaluates to `0`, though note that `10` ^ `0` is `1`. `0` times `1` is still `0`.

You can confirm this by testing your JSON at **[JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)**, which proves that the following is perfectly valid JSON:

```
{
    "number": 0E0
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: `0E0` doesn't mean 0 to the power of 0; it means 0 times *10 to the power of 0*.

Comment: ^ Correct, missed that out; updated to fix. The answer is still zero though :)

Comment: "*though note that 0 ^ 0 would be 1*" seems kind of superfluous and unnecessary. Why include that? It might confuse folks.